Mapped types from arrays and generics
Consider the following code:
type ArrLit = readonly ['a', 'b']

type GenericRef<T extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: "here"
}

type MappedThroughGeneric = GenericRef<ArrLit>
/* type MappedThroughGeneric = ["here", "here"] */

type MappedDirectly = {
  [K in keyof ArrLit]: "here"
}
/*
type MappedDirectly = {
    [x: number]: "here";
    0: "here";
    1: "here";
    length: "here";
    toString: "here";
    ...
  }
*/

Link to the playground
My question is: why using the extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> makes the mapped type use only explicit keys and return an array while using an array literal doesn't cause the mapping to be inferred in the same way? Isn't the array literal explicitly of a ReadonlyArray type?

The difference you’re seeing is due to how TypeScript handles array literals and the ReadonlyArray type.

When you define ArrLit as readonly ['a', 'b'], TypeScript infers a tuple type for it, not an array. Tuples in TypeScript are a way of defining an array with fixed types and a fixed length. So, ArrLit is inferred as a tuple of length 2, with the first element being a string ‘a’ and the second a string ‘b’.
When you use ArrLit directly in a mapped type, TypeScript uses the keys of the tuple, which include numeric keys for the elements and all the additional keys from the Array prototype like length, toString, etc.
the difference is due to TypeScript treating tuples and arrays differently. Tuples have additional keys that arrays don’t have, and these keys are included when you use a tuple in a mapped type. So it’s not about readonly or mutability, but about tuples vs arrays.
